# Unable to access shared virtual machines remotely hosted on vmware workstation pro on ubuntu 19 or ubuntu 20.04

Tags: vmware-workstation, ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-19.10

## Original question asked on r/vmware

> Installed latest VMware Workstation (15.5.5) on Ubuntu 20.04. When I
> try to connect to this PC from another PC with same version of VMware
> Workstation, I'm getting error that VMware Workstation Server
> unexpectedly closed connection. Tried to check Vmware logs, but
> nothing interesting there. On Ubuntu 19.10 there are no such problems.
> Did anybody faced with this problem? Are there any ways to resolve it?

*NOTE*: u/EvilEarthWorm is wrong about 19.10 not having this issue :P but that's neither here nor there,

## My rephrasing of the same problem:

When attempting to connect to a VMware workstation pro 14 or VMware workstation pro 15's shared virtual machines, running on Ubuntu 19.x or Ubuntu 20.x as host, using either another vmware workstation (say running on Windows or another Linux) or using Mac Fusion the `/usr/lib/vmware/bin/hostd` mysteriously crashes. There is a report created in `/var/crash/_usr_lib_vmware_bin_appLoader.`*`<id>`*`.crash` but not much info because no debugging symbols are available.

Typically the remote connection drops with mysterious messages like: **`A secure connection to the server could not be stablished`**

[image: Mysterious message on VMWare Fusion]

What's happening? Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the answer, initially posted by me on r/vmware on reddit but figured it's better to post it here too:

## TLDR;

Here are is a simple fix to the issue on Ubuntu 19 / 20  or any other system where attempts to access shared virtual machines is crashing  (i.e. `/var/lib/vmware/bin/hostd`) is mysteriously crashing.

```
cp /etc/pam.d/vmware-authd ~/vmware-authd.backup
sed  -e '/pam_cap/s/^.*$/# -- pam_cap does not work for multithreaded apps -- /' /etc/pam.d/common-auth | sudo tee /etc/pam.d/common-auth-mt
sudo -i -e 's/common-auth/common-auth-mt/' /etc/pam.d/vmware-authd
```

## Details on why this works,

The culprit is then entry in  `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` that includes `pam_cap.so`.  It turns out `/usr/lib/vmware/bin/hostd` is a MULTITHREADED app and `pam_cap.so` does NOT work with them:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The pam_cap PAM module sets the current process' inheritable capabilities.
>
> Capabilities are read from the /etc/security/capability.conf config file, or alternate file specified with the config= option.
>
> The module must not be called by a multithreaded application.
>
> (source: pam_cap(8) man page)

and it turns out `hostd` is multithreaded :P

So we create a "multithreaded" version of all the "common-*" files (it turns out that it was only common-auth) and use that for our multithreaded apps.

### Of course you can do what TLDR; above did by hand as under:

```
❯ /bin/cat /etc/pam.d/vmware-authd

#%PAM-1.0
auth     include        common-auth-mt
account  include        common-account
password include        common-password
session  include        common-session
```

and

```
❯ cat common-auth-mt

#
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# -- pam_cap does not work for multithreaded apps --
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

Hopefully this is clear enough.

## More info

BTW this also works for mysql mariadb and other multithreaded app auth issues by checking if their pam modules somehow include pam_cap.